# Suitescript - Fetch and display shipping cost on sales order form

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

Is there a way to display the shipping costs in creating a sales order like what the NetSuite web form has? As far as I know, there's a setting per shipping item if it is set to a flat rate, a shipping table, and other rules to be considered like maximum rates, etc.

So, should I do a manual computation instead? Or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using SuiteScript, use the **nlapiCreateRecord** method shown below:

```
var record = nlapiCreateRecord('salesorder', {'recordmode': 'dynamic'});
```

> Setting recordmode to dynamic is important otherwise the
>   computations will always be 0.

Next, set the shipping method with its internal ID.

```
record.setFieldValue('shipmethod', input.shipping_method);
```

Next, loop through the list of items from your json data, then commit line item before going to the next iteration:

```
// sample json data on one item (all attributes are internal IDs except quantity)
[
    {"id":6657,"quantity":2,"units":16,"price":1,"taxcode":22},
    {"id":3941,"quantity":1,"units":16,"price":1,"taxcode":22}
]

// start
    record.selectNewLineItem('item');
    record.setCurrentLineItemValue('quantity', item.quantity);
    // duplicate setCurrentLineItemValue and change the parameters to 
    // units, price, taxcode respectively
    record.commitLineItem('item');
// end
```

Lastly, you can get the shipping cost by using **getFieldValue** method:

```
record.getFieldValue('shippingcost');
```

Note that you can also get the values for subtotal, taxtotal, and total (or overall total cost).